# Sequelize include inside another include

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

**The problem:**

I can't retrieve an include inside include with Sequelize@5.21.2.
The first include its OK. But when i try to grab the other include, i only receive null.

**The code:**

```js
let planCodes = ['monthly', 'annual'];

const plans = await Plan.findAll({
    where: {
        code: {
            [Op.or]: planCodes
        }
    },
    include: [{
        model: PlanItem,
        as: 'plan_items',
        include: [{
            model: Product,
            as: 'product',
        }]
    }]
});
```

Model associations:

**Plan**

```js
Plan.hasMany(PlanItem, { foreignKey: "plan_id" });
```

**PlanItem**

```js
PlanItem.hasOne(Product, { foreignKey: "plan_item_id" });
```

**The response:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 175231,
    "name": "mensal",
    "interval": "months",
    "interval_count": 1,
    "code": "monthly",
    "status": "active",
    "metadata": {},
    "created_at": "XXXX-XX-XX",
    "updated_at": "XXXX-XX-XX",
    "plan_items": [
      {
        "id": 190651,
        "plan_id": 175231,
        "product_id": 655939,
        "created_at": "XXXX-XX-XX",
        "updated_at": "XXXX-XX-XX",
        "product": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I already checked all details with the IDs at database and everything is OK.

Comment: Show model definitions as well

Answer (score 0):

I will admit that Sequelize likes to take all the spontaneity out of relationships, but you should use your alias in both the model definition AND the query.  And they have to be the same.  I'm sure there is *some* leeway, as you are, in fact, returning `plan_items` values.  But whether "best practice" or "mandate", give this a go:

```js
Plan.hasMany(PlanItem, { as: "plan_items", foreignKey: "plan_id" });
PlanItem.hasOne(Product, { as: "product", foreignKey: "plan_item_id" });

// You may also try defining the Product/PlanItem relationship the other way
Product.belongsTo(PlanItem, { as: "plan_item", foreignKey: "plan_item_id" });
```

Comment: Already tried this out, and does't work.
The solution was to create another query for each product... Not the way I wanted but solved for now. 

Thanks for the answer anyway!